# ASK vb net make function COM Player allied chess, come near to the point at (x, y)?

Tags: vb.net

PIC1>>>
if {(4, 5), (5, 5), (6, 5), (7, 5)} = wall (restricted area)

if (5, 3) = "COM Player"

if (5, 6) = "Me player"

"com player" start first (one step, his choice "left", "right", "Top", "Bottom")

whereas Me player, (one step, choice, "Right", "Up", "Down)

I would like to create a function "com player" position , to select a point (x, y) is approaching the point "me player"

for example to the right one step "COM Player"(5, 4) (automatically choosing and not random)

PIC2>>>
"com player" after the end turn, "me player" chose to go away (5, 7), to avoid in eating "com player", "me player" end turn

PIC3>>>
during a turn, the "player com"
I would like to create a function "player com" between (4, 4) or (6, 4), to choose the shortest distance to the "me player"
if choose (4, 4) = 6 step closer
if choose (6, 4) = 8 step closer

I want "com player" can make choices "(4, 4) = 6 step closer"

msgbox("(4, 4)") <<<<<<<<<<<<<< how do I get this

[PIC>>>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9l00k.jpg)

Comment: Look up the A* (prounounced A-Star) path-finding algorithm.  Here is a tutorial for beginners:  http://www.policyalmanac.org/games/aStarTutorial.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you

link you gave is not to VB .Net, but C ++

and I am very air thanks, above the link you gave, finally I can get what I want here
http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?666893-(VB6-amp-VB-Net)-A*-Pathfinding-(Fast-and-Easy)